# Connect tcpListen without define the IP of Server on Client Side?

Tags: vb.net

now i'm making a program that work on client-server.
in vb net i was using socket communication.
the problem that i got is how to connect the server without define ip of server on client side. Why i was ask this?

Well, sometimes the ip of server is always changing. maybe it happen when the computer is restarted.
for now i'm, to connect both computers i use Socket Communication. but before we use it, in client side and server side must be defined first.
perhaps for define IP is unnecessary?

What would be the best way to solve this case?

Comment: Do not run a server with a dynamic IP. Obviously the client needs to know what to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

The `Socket.Connect` method can take either a host name or an IPAddress, so as long as the server's host name does not change, you can use that.

Comment: hostname? that wasn't my purpose. i mean, how can i get IP of server maybe with "autofind IP" so define IP or host name is unnecessary.

Comment: If you aren't connecting by host name, and you aren't connecting by IP address, how do you expect to connect?  It's not clear at all what you are asking.  Please clarify.

Comment: if i connecting by hostname or IP address, what if i'm Applying on different computers? Well, thats my main problem and that was why i hate Defining hostname

Comment: I still don't follow you.  What do you want to use as an address?

Comment: most client-server programs that i have met, they are using "auto search ip address" you should try to see games based client-server. i think it's a smart program

Comment: For something like that, you'd need to have the server periodically broadcast its presence to the entire network using UDP and the clients could each just wait and listen for one of those messages.  You could also look into existing self-discovery protocols such as bonjour.

Comment: how can i send the existence of server to the entire network? Would you like to tell me the algorithm? 
i know it certainly to use UDP to listen and without accept connection such as TCP.
as far as i know about IP Address, They have 4 part and each part has size such as byte, i mean like this "255.255.255.255".